# How do I get this locked doorknob off?

Tags: lock, doorknob

I'm writing this on my phone (laptop is locked in my room), so I apologize if this isn't formatted well. I also know nothing about tools/doorknobs, so forgive me for not knowing the exact terminology for stuff.

Left in a rush and accidentally locked myself out of my bedroom. It is a button lock. This has happened to me before, and usually I'm able to get back in by putting a small flathead screwdriver into a round latch thing and turning it until it unlocks. It's so worn down now that that method isn't working anymore. There are no exposed screws, only this tab on the side, but I'm unable to fit anything in it.

[image: doortab]

[image: doorlatchthing]
Just trying to get back in my room and I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Is there a hole in the centre of the knob?  If there is, push something into it, a nail, small screwdriver, whatever fits.

Comment: There's no hole in the middle, no. Completely smooth. No tabs/slots/holes/etc on the other side of the knob either.

Comment: The tab on the side holds the trim plate (escutcheon) to the lockset, by spring tension. If you jam a screwdriver under the trim plate (be careful not to gouge the door) and pry, the plate should pop forward towards the knob. Then you might be able to grab the damaged "emergency access turn-button" with a plier or something and turn it to unlock the door.

Comment: If you can afford it, maybe you should call a locksmith.

Comment: Might be able to slide something stiff like a credit card, thin piece of metal, between door and frame to push latch in.

Comment: Jimmy, so do you mean the plate attached to the door itself or that tab? Neither seem to be giving.

Comment: I have a thin metal ruler I tried sliding/pressing in the door but it didn't do anything either.

Comment: If you can get a narrow putty knife wedge it between the door trim and the jamb right next to the knob. You'll need to separate the trin from the jamb to get the putty knife in. Push it in hard and work it against the latch until the latch slips back into the lockset.

Comment: Once you get the door open, I'd _strongly_ recommend that you replace the knob set, just in case this happens again. Of course, that seems likely, since you've done it so many times that you've worn out the emergency access.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you could pry off the collar using the little flat tab on the right side of it.  On a security lock you could not do this but this is a privacy lock and usually you can.

Then maybe you'll have access to grab that button with pliers or to unlock the door some other way.

Sometimes on a privacy lock like this the knob itself can be pried off this way too. We can't see it but maybe there's a tab or detent that allows you to remove the knob.  If you can get the knob AND collar off, it should be easy to unlock.

Then replace the whole thing!

Comment: Sometimes the knob can be released by pushing upwards on a tab on the underside of its stem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the screws and the knob should pop off. Press the shaft out that is remaining and you should be able to push the other side off, you will hear it hit the floor unless it is well padded. That gives you access the mechanism. Use a screwdriver to rotate the square hole and it should open. That worked with mine which looked about the same. The screws went into metal studs connected to the handle on the other side which was held just by screw tension.